# MVC3 Routes with areas... a little confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC3 site with 2 areas plus the common area.  I also have a route specified for paginating lists of items.  My `Register_Routes` method looks like so:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Paginate", // Route name
            "{controller}/Paginate/{itemsPerPage}/{pageNumber}/{searchString}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", itemsPerPage = SiteSettings.ItemsPerPage, pageNumber = 1, searchString = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

What I've noticed (and don't understand) is if I log out from my home page, the redirect from my login page looks like

```
http://localhost:62695/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fPaginate
```

... and upon logging in, I end up on my home page, except with a URL of:

```
http://localhost:62695/Home/Paginate
```

I'm fairly certain at this point that I've screwed something up with the route map, but it seems right to me.  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
per suggestion, I changed my routes to look like this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Paginate", // Route name
            "{controller}/Paginate/{itemsPerPage}/{pageNumber}/{searchString}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", searchString = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

... and the home index pages do indeed seem to work properly, but now the paginates don't:

```
        return RedirectToAction("Paginate", new { itemsPerPage = SiteSettings.ItemsPerPage, pageNumber = 1, searchString = string.Empty });
```

in a Admin\HomeController yields the URL:

```
http://localhost:62695/Admin/Users/Paginate?itemsPerPage=25&pageNumber=1
```

so I'm still doing something wrong here.

**UPDATE 2**
OK, this is how I got it to work the way I wanted it to:
My `RegisterRoutes` method now looks like this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{area}/{controller}/Paginate/{itemsPerPage}/{pageNumber}/{searchString}", // URL with parameters
            new {area = string.Empty, controller = "Home", action="Paginate", searchString = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {area = string.Empty, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

... but this was not enough to fix the routing issues.  Additionally to this, I needed to add the route to my area registrations.  My AdminAreaRegistration looks like this:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Admin/{controller}/Paginate/{itemsPerPage}/{pageNumber}/{searchString}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Paginate", searchString = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

This, in addition to changing to `RedirectToRoute` for my connections, made my URLs all pretty and working at the same time.  All the answers helped to get to my goal, I +1'd everyone and chose the answer that got me closest to the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(null, // do not name your routes, it's a "magic string"
    "{controller}/Paginate/{itemsPerPage}/{pageNumber}/{searchString}",
        new 
        { 
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index", 
            searchString = UrlParameter.Optional
        } 
    );

// instead of RedirectToAction, try RedirectToRoute, and do not use the route name
return RedirectToRoute(new 
    { 
        controller = "Home",
        area = "AreaName",
        itemsPerPage = SiteSettings.ItemsPerPage, 
        pageNumber = 1, 
        searchString = string.Empty, 
    }
);
```

Comment: That does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: I forgot about the area route fragment, and have updated my answer. Exactly what action method is the Paginate URL supposed to map to? `HomeController.Index(int itemsPerPage, int pageNumber, string searchString)?` If not, you need to change your `MapRoute`.

Answer (score 2):

Routes are evaluated in the order they are registered. The redirects are being generated by the first route that you registered, especially since you declared default values for all of the segments. You might want to consider defining a more specific route

**UPDATE**
Use RedirectToRoute instead of RedirectToAction to get your desired URL generation

```
RedirectToRoute("Paginate", new { itemsPerPage = SiteSettings.ItemsPerPage, pageNumber = 1, searchString = string.Empty });
```

Comment: OK, if I remove the default values for `itemsPerPage` and `pageNumber`, my home page seems to work correctly... but my `RedirectToAction` values now list stuff in standard GET format (i.e., `http://localhost:62695/Admin/Users/Paginate?itemsPerPage=25&pageNumber=1`) instead of the nice pretty `http://localhost:62695/Admin/Users/Paginate/25/1` that I was aiming  for.

Comment: you should be using RedirectToRoute instead. I've updated the answer above

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason you return to the URL `http://localhost:62695/Home/Paginate` is because when you log in you return to the URL specified, namely the `?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fPaginate` part of `http://localhost:62695/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fPaginate`. Is that not the URL of your home page? You never specified.

It could be that the first definition takes precedence also, not sure where I heard that, so maybe if you put the default definition first it will grab that.

Comment: Ah, see, cecilphillip thinks so too. Try re-ordering your route defintions.

Comment: hmm... my home page should be `/`, plain and simple.  So don't define defaults... hmm.